# node.js callback inside mysql result loop

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to get my head around this non-blocking business.

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong here? I have tried to add a **retrieveContactName** function which gets more information from the db before writing to socket. I have tried to make it a callback but i get the error at bottom.

```
case 'getConversations':
    var sip  = parts[1];
    var pass = parts[2].replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''); //strip that carriage return
    var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(session) FROM im WHERE sip = "+connection.escape(sip)+" AND password = "+connection.escape(pass)+" ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) winston.warn(err);  
        for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            retrieveContactName(results[i].session, sip, pass, function(value) {
                sock.write('Conversations '+results[i].session+' '+value+'\n');
            });
        }
    });
break;
```

elsewhere

```
function retrieveContactName(session, user, pass, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT `im_from` FROM `im` WHERE `session` = "+connection.escape(session)+" AND `im_to` != "+connection.escape(session)+" AND `sip` = "+connection.escape(user)+"  AND `password` = "+connection.escape(pass)+" LIMIT 1";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) winston.warn(err);  
        if (results.length > 0 ) { 
            callback(results[0].im_from);
        } else {
            callback(session.replace("contact:",""));
        }
    });
}
```

and my error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/socket/server.js:44:47
    at Query._callback (/home/ubuntu/socket/server.js:79:4)
    at Query.end (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
    at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/socket/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:88:20)
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(results)` after `connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {` in the first section of code?

Comment: @pebbl i get [ { session: 'contact:447884001671' },
  { session: 'contact:5551000009484' },
  { session: 'contact:447825846024' },
  { session: 'contact:447960685400' } ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is down to not fully understanding scope, basically the issue is occurring here:

```
for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) { 
    retrieveContactName(results[i].session, sip, pass, function(value) {
        sock.write('Conversations '+results[i].session+' '+value+'\n');
    });
}
```

The above will not work as you expect, all because by the time your callback fires `i` will not have the value you expect... it will most likely be equal to `results.length` which will give you an `undefined` slot in `results`. This is because the `for` will most likely have continued on and finished it's execution before the callbacks ever occur. This is the principal of non-blocking, code does not wait, it carries on, and your callbacks have to be prepared for this.

In order to use the value of `i`, or any variable that may change it's value outside the scope of your callback, you need to capture that value and store it with your callback. There are a few ways to do this but the nicest way is to pass the data your callback requires in as arguments — so you need to pass the `results[i].session` (passed into retrieveContactName) on to your callback.

```
function retrieveContactName(session, user, pass, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT `im_from` FROM `im` WHERE `session` = "+connection.escape(session)+" AND `im_to` != "+connection.escape(session)+" AND `sip` = "+connection.escape(user)+"  AND `password` = "+connection.escape(pass)+" LIMIT 1";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) winston.warn(err);  
        if (results.length > 0 ) { 
            callback(results[0].im_from, session);
        } else {
            callback(session.replace("contact:",""), session);
        }
    });
}
```

And then:

```
for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) { 
    retrieveContactName(results[i].session, sip, pass, function(value, session) {
        sock.write('Conversations '+session+' '+value+'\n');
    });
}
```

Obviously this is just a quick example, it may be best to pass in the actual result row — depending on what you want / need.

Comment: and if i want to call a second function now i just have to nest the callbacks right?

Comment: @VinceLowe no problem :) it's a typical issue to hit when you start dealing with callbacks -- best advice is to trap any values you need when you get them. Don't rely on vars having the same value later...

Comment: @VinceLowe You can, but you will start getting very deep in callbacks if your code is complex. Most people will implement some form of library or wrapping code to help them handle deferring and combining callbacks into lists that fire in sequence... this link can give you a rough idea -- http://howtonode.org/promises -- other than that a good book is http://nodetuts.com/handson-nodejs-book.html.. Also you may find your database object has functionality to help chaining requests.

Answer (score 0):

results[i] may be out of scope inside the callback

```
case 'getConversations':
var sip  = parts[1];
var pass = parts[2].replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''); //strip that carriage return
var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(session) FROM im WHERE sip = "+connection.escape(sip)+" AND password = "+connection.escape(pass)+" ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
    if (err) winston.warn(err);  
    for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) { 
        retrieveContactName(results[i].session, sip, pass, function(value) {
            sock.write('Conversations '+results[i].session+' '+value+'\n');
        });
    }
});
```

break;

can you place a console.log(results) just above:

```
 sock.write('Conversations '+results[i].session+' '+value+'\n');
```